# Library compatibility between C# .NET vs C# Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I wanted to tryout C# for general purpose programming (not web development). I program in Windows environment, but I would like to avoid coding specifically for Windows (.NET), because I want to keep the option open for a future migration to Linux.

1. Are there any specific libraries in C# .NET that wouldn't work in C# Mono for general purpose programming work (not interested in Windows Forms, Silverlight and stuff like that) ?
2. Is there any internet link of things/features that provides a list that works on C# .NET wouldn't work on C# Mono or vice versa? I didn't readily find anything in google per se.

Note: I would be interested in specific answers, not opinions of which is better or worse (thanks!)

Comment: The mono compatibility when site resume #2 http://mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: thanks, I looked at that page, but these are very specific to application/web development. Anything for general purpose?

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph before the list there? It specifically says `The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is:
Everything in .NET 4.5 except WPF, WWF, and with limited WCF and limited ASP.NET 4.5 async stack.`

Comment: I did. But there are a lot of statistical/mathematical libraries released by independent vendors. That list merely talks about standard stuff that Mono developers worry about. One of things I was hoping to get from here is experience from C# users who use libraries other than those standard app/web. For example,  http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/ is a library released for .NET (C# and F#) and I couldn't find if it works under Mono.

Comment: I think that you can generally assume the answer to be no. As far as I know, Mono is not binary compatible. It requires a recompile. If the vendor has not compiled it for mono, you probably can't do anything with it. Because I'm only mostly sure, I haven't made this an answer.

Comment: Mono is binary compatible and does not require a recompile. Generally the answer is "yes" unless the library makes use of P/Invoke or doesn't properly use the System.IO.Path methods to properly construct file paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It is possible for a CLR assembly (even in the form of a DLL, as mentioned in the comments) to be read by Mono, as long as it does not have dependencies that do not exist in Mono, because...
2. ...not every piece of code that compiles for .NET will compile for Mono, since there are lots of Windows-specific things in .NET (not strictly part of C#) that aren't implemented (WPF, ASP.NET async stack) or don't make sense at all in Linux (COM is one such example, I think).

Fortunately, there is [a list of what .NET features are implemented in Mono](http://mono-project.com/Compatibility). Even more fortunately, it seems they have [an app that tells you a priori whether your code makes use of anything not implemented in Mono](http://mono-project.com/MoMA) (but I have never tried it).

Comment: This is not entirely correct. A C# library compiled with .Net will work correctly on Mono, as long as it does not use any windows-specific technology (such as WPF). You do not need to recompile the dll. This is how e.g. [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com) works: a single .Net dll that can work on both .Net and Mono (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X), without recompilation.

Comment: @TheFiddler That's strange, since I remember trying this with a very minimal library and it failed. It must have been something else, because it seems you are right - a portably written DLL should run. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

if you install xamarin (you need Pro or bigger so you have VS integration) you can create Portable Class Library that targets xamarin (which is based on mono) and visual studio will allow you to only use classes that are compatible with mono.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/

apparently you can also use xamarin studio to create a PCL and there is a free version of that.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't think Mono is limited to PCL. Those are more for targeting the mobile platform and limitations between them.

Comment: @kenny actually it is exactly the opposite, (in the case with xamarin) in the pcl you are supposed to put all your code that is not platform specific and create a separate implementation for the UI for each platform.

Comment: Yes but Mono is NOT limited to PCL, far from it so it is not a good indication of what will run. PCL is good for enforcing abstraction but most of .NET code will run on Mono without an issue.

Comment: Portable Class Library is obsolete. Now is .NET Standard.